# Make a radio station

Tags: internet-radio

At my school, last year, they created a radio station for European School Radio. I saw that they used windows, and I am on linux. I want to see how can I create a radio but not online, I want to be heard on radios.

How can it be done on Ubuntu?

Thanks. IF you can give something to read, I really didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you trying to make an online radio? I can help you only if its online

Comment: Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

[Credit goes to Free software magazine](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/create_radio_station_five_minutes_airtime_20_ubuntu_or_debian)

- open your terminal and paste this

  ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- paste this line at ending

  ```
  deb http://apt.sourcefabric.org/ saucy main
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
  ```

  save & close that file.
- Then paste these command in terminal one after one

  ```
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get install sourcefabric-keyring
       sudo apt-get install postgresql
       sudo apt-get install icecast2
       sudo apt-get install airtime
  ```

Now follow the Configuration File at manual: http://en.flossmanuals.net/airtime-en-2-0/

Comment: Good answer Still **1)** Need a transmitter and **2)** a frequency band to broadcast on *(vaguely legally, that is)*

Comment: the transmitter can cost tuns of money!!!